# AWS Application Load balancer, target group health check fails.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am setting up an application load balancer.

The ALB,  has 1 listener 
http: 80 to the target-group
target-group has port 3000
I also have an auto scaling group that points to the target group and is setup to create 2 instances. 
Cluster group is setup, with service that runs 4 tasks.
I setup the service to use the alb and http:80 port. The 
task created has a dynamic host port and container port 3000.

I have checked my security groups and I have inbound setup to accept port 3000, and 80 and outbound takes all traffic.

All the instances in the target-group are unhealthy
I can ssh into the ec2 instances and docker ps -a returns two docker containers.
I logged out and ran curl -i ec2-user@ec2-22-236-243-39.compute-4.amazonaws.com:3000/health-check-target-page I get 
Failed to connect to ec2-user@ec2-22-236-243-39.compute-4.amazonaws.com port 3000: Connection refused

I tried same command with port 80 and I get 
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

I'm still learning AWS so hope this info helps. Let me know what I am missing here.

Thanks!

Comment: When I do curl inside the container it returns hello world. But when I try to do it outside the container it times out.  Anyone have any idea what I need to do to be able to access the ec2 instance from outside so the target groups can access the instances???

Comment: Your web server process binds a listen socket to an IP address. `netstat -a -n | grep 3000` should find that.  If it's 127.0.0.1, that's your problem.  If that returns nothing, that's a problem, too.  What do you see?

Comment: I think I found what the problem was. It was my security groups. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot -  am having the same issue, I run "netstat -a -n | grep 3000" it is showing private IPv6 of my server with port 3000. But still instance is unhealthy, please help